# I'm having an issue with "jQuery not defined"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got the same plugin on two different versions of a site, one version everything is fine, the other version shows "jQuery not defined" for the plugin WordPress Social Stream.  I don't think it's a plugin issue and probably has a pretty simple fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  The URL is http://designatwork.net/dawnew/newsroom/.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid question on StackOverflow, but I would like to answer this, as I don't want to demotivate someone on this holiday.

Your scripts are loaded at the bottom, so technically, `jQuery` is not defined at the place you have added the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($){var config = {feeds: {},remove:"",max: "limit",days: 14,limit: 14,cache: false,speed: 3000,height: 1000,twitterId: "70776644",rotate: {delay: 0, direction: "up"},wall: true,container: "dcwss",cstream: "stream",content: "dcwss-content",imagePath: "http://designatwork.net/dawnew/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-stream/images/dcwss-dark/",iconPath: "http://designatwork.net/dawnew/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-stream/images/dcwss-dark/"};if(!jQuery().dcSocialStream) { $.getScript("http://designatwork.net/dawnew/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-stream/js/jquery.social.stream.wall.1.6.js", function(){}); $.getScript("http://designatwork.net/dawnew/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-stream/js/jquery.social.stream.1.5.11.min.js", function(){$("#social-stream-45").dcSocialStream(config);}); } else {$("#social-stream-45.dc-wall").dcSocialStream(config);}});</script>
```

Moving it to the end of the document will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page is trying to use jQuery (line 97) before the jQuery library is included (line 132)